# Can I test cross-browser javascript via the command line?

Tags: javascript, testing, cross-browser

Firefox has the [JSShell for SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell). Do the other major browsers Chrome and Safari have a command-line interface to their javascript engines? If so, this would be a great *lightweight* way to test javascript to ensure that it runs cross-browser without having to open a full browser.

Comment: cross browser issues are far more complex than just the javascript engine

Comment: Agreed but tools like these help with a significant part of the problem. When html or css works differently in different browsers, your web app may look a little different, but different javascript implementations can cause web app to not work at all.